# How to change the HeaderLayout background of Navigation Drawer programatically?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationbar, navigationview, android-navigationview

**Question**

Actually I want to change a HeaderLayout background of `Navigation Drawer` programmatically,

**nav_header_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar_fr"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:id="@+id/header">

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And I try to change header background with this code :

```
 LinearLayout header;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  header= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.header);

  header.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.side_nav_bar_ru);
```

but an error is displayed

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference

Someone help me please :(

Comment: is that xml called activity_main.xml? because it should if you want your code to work...

Comment: @Nanoc : yes it's called :(

Comment: Your findViewById is looking for "header" inside activity_main.xml but it is not there, it is in nav_header_main.xml thats why it returns null, below answer is right but i think thats not a valid solution to you...

Comment: @Nanoc : you not know a solution to my problem please?

Comment: Move your "header" view to the other xml or get it from the correct xml whatever is easier to you.

Comment: @Nanoc : I finally found the solution but thank you  ( i do this :  navigationView.findViewById(R.id.header).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.side_nav_bar_sport);  )

Answer (score 4):

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.header).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.side_nav_bar_ru);
```

Comment: I would suggest providing some details to how the answer works

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: This works for me. Interestingly findView(id) didn't find the View referenced inside the drawer layout under "app:headerLayout". Only Specifically inside "getheaderView()" I found my Drawer title.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
```